# React redux-form, react-select

Tags: javascript, redux-form, react-select

Hi I am facing an issue in redux-form, I am not sure but if I use react-select/ or any select with redux-form I need to click twice on select in order to expand my list. Only html select works fine.

I know this issue is happening because the input fields dispatch onBlur event actions. If I suppress the onBlur event it works perfectly, however I need the blur event for my future work.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Steps to reproduce:
1) Click on Load account button
2) Type something in any input field 
3) Click on react-select select comp !!!!! need to click twice to expand it

If you directly click on react-select comp drop down it works fine.

I am attaching link of my issue

https://codesandbox.io/s/n791ln05mj

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes finally I got my answer the dump component should be outside the render method.

https://q24rlrnzj.codesandbox.io/